# The execution order of setTimeout and AJAX onload callback function

Tags: javascript, ajax, settimeout, asynccallback, eventqueue

I am fairly new to javascript and after having a basic understanding of how event loop, callback queue and webAPIs work together to achieve asynchronous in Javascript. I have a following simple code including setTimeout and AJAX to test if my understanding of the executing order of code is correct or not.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  alert('timeout1')
}, 0);
req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("get", "https://reqres.in/api/products/3");
req.onload = function(data) {
  alert('request done'+data.target.responseText);
};
req.send();
alert('123');
alert('456');
alert('789');
```

```html
hello,world
```

I was expecting the result to be like:

alert('123') -> alert('456') -> alert('789') -> alert('timeout1') -> alert('request done')

What I was thinking is that first the `setTimeout()` belongs to browser API ,so it will be popped out from the call stack of javascript and be executed outside of javascript engine, then the scripts keeps on executing the next line of code. As it got to the line
`req.send()`, it will also be executed outside of javascript engine and then the scripts goes on.

And since I set the timeout to be 0 sec, the `setTimeout()` callback function `()=>{alert('timeout1')}` shall be push into the callback queue first before the `req.onload` callback function `function(){alert('request done');}` (after all, the request needs to take some time to wait for response, even if it's super quick). So the order of execution after the call stack is empty would be

1. alert('timeout1')
2. alert('request done')

But the result is :

alert('123') -> alert('456') -> alert('789') -> *alert('request done') -> alert('timeout1')*

Apparently my thought is wrong.But I just can't figure it out.

Please correct me if I was wrong on this.
Thank you for checking my question!

Comment: debugging with alerts is bad since it causes pauses in execution. You really should use console.log()

Comment: _“What I was thinking is that first the `setTimeout()` belongs to browser API”_ — Why would that make a difference? Both `setTimeout` and XHR are Web APIs. What makes a difference is which queue in the event loop the functions will be added to.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yeah I understand that both setTimeout and XHR are web APIs. What I'm confused about is the executing order. I though that the setTimeout call back function is the first entering into the call back queue, and then is the onload call back function . So I assumed  "alert('timeout1')" will appear first , then is the alert('request done'). Thanks for your reply!